How to calculate the cross-correlation of two signals that have different sizes?
I have two video signals of the same video. One encoded in MPEG format and the other in H.263 format. These signals are represented in .txt files with the frame sizes in an array.
I need to calculate the cross-correlation without losing or adding extra data, even though they have different sizes.
The file with MPEG frames has 89000 frames and H.263 has 17000 frames.
I have already made several attempts, 1. using Python functions such as numpy.correlate, 2. padding (adding zeros in the sequence), 3. truncation (removing data, but I lost information), 4. linear interpolation, 5. transforming to the frequency domain with the fourier transform before cross-correlate, 6. normalize before cross correlation, etc.
Any suggestions on the best way to do this?
Grateful.

I would be really helpful if you can add 1) what exactly is your goal? What do you need the cross correlation for ? 2) what about the results that you got with the things you already tried is wrong? 3) do the two streams have the same frame rate? If yes, why is the number of frames so different ?



I want to cross-correlate two videos in different formats (MPEG and H.263)... it's just a conceptual exercise.


The results are wrong because I cannot modify the signal content using padding or truncation. However, I also cannot do cross-correlation if I have vectors with different sizes.


The two signals do not have the same bit rate


the frame numbers are so different because different forms of compression were used. One was in MPEG and the other in H.263. This generated two different signals, but with the same video.


